# Android Data binding, The value of attribute "android:text" associated with an element type "TextView" must not contain the '<' character

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I am using the **Android Data Binding library**. I have a requirement that if the bound number is less than 10, I need to show it with a zero appended (like `01`, `05`), and else show the normal number.

Here's the relevant part of my layout:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/tlm_no"
     style="@style/BlackSmallTextStyle"
     android:layout_width="@dimen/study_plan_icon_width"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@id/tlm_image"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
     android:text="@{studyPlanDetailVM.studyPlanDetail.learningPlanResource[0] < 10 ? `0` + studyPlanDetailVM.studyPlanDetail.learningPlanResource[0] : studyPlanDetailVM.studyPlanDetail.learningPlanResource[0]}" />
```

But when I build the project it throws the following error:
`The value of attribute “android:text” associated with an element type “TextView” must not contain the '<' character`

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: So, what the error is following ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use `&lt;` instead of `<`

Use `&gt;` instead of `>`

Use `&amp;` instead of `&`